# Producing a Running or Cumulative Percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a situation that I can model easily in Excel, but I'm having trouble with in SQL Server. I experimented heavily with window functions (like lag() ) because I feel like they're part of the answer here, but there must be a component to them that I'm overlooking. I'm trying to get a running percentage, but the calculation which produces the new percentage has the previous percentage rolled into it.

Below is a screenshot from Excel with data and the desired result. I've added some explanation below it. I'm trying to produce column C in SQL Server (percent of additive).

[image]

Row 1: We start with a vat containing 200 gallons of some solution. We add 200 gallons of additive. So the percentage of additive to the original solution is 50%.

Row 2: After some consumption, we're left with 300 gallons of 50% solution. Now we add 200 gallons of additive. So our new additive percentage is 50% of the 300 (150), plus the 200 we just added (150+200=350). And we divide that by the total (300+200=500). So 350/500 = 0.7 or 70%.

And so on.

As you can see, as we keep adding additive and consuming the solution, the percentage approaches 100%.

Here's some code to produce a temp table with the data shown above. Appreciate any help.

```
create table #x (starting_vat_level int, additive_added int, pct_of_additive float null)
insert into #x values (200, 200, NULL)
insert into #x values (300, 150, NULL)
insert into #x values (100, 50, NULL)
insert into #x values (100, 100, NULL)
insert into #x values (150, 50, NULL)
insert into #x values (150, 100, NULL)
insert into #x values (200, 150, NULL)
insert into #x values (300, 50, NULL)
insert into #x values (300, 100, NULL)
insert into #x values (150, 50, NULL)
insert into #x values (100, 80, NULL)
insert into #x values (50, 10, NULL)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+calculate+running+total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the `pct_of_additive` recursively.

```
with rcte as
(
    select id, starting_vat_level, additive_added, 
           pct_of_additive = convert(float, additive_added * 1.0 
                                          / (starting_vat_level + additive_added))
    from   #x
    where  id = 1
  
    union all

    select x.id, x.starting_vat_level, x.additive_added,
           pct_of_additive = convert(float, 
                           ((r.pct_of_additive * x.starting_vat_level) + x.additive_added)
                           / (x.starting_vat_level + x.additive_added))
    from   rcte r
           inner join #x x on r.id = x.id - 1
  
)
select *
  from rcte
 order by id
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3--fjO3E)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid recursion, but if that's the answer, it explains why I couldn't accomplish this with lead/lag or the like.